# give type to accumulator with array reduce typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, reduce

I am generating object with time intervals with some function. It returns `["00:00", "00:30", "01:00"]` ... , but for my purpose I need to have obj-map `{{ "00:00": "00:00" }, { "00:30": "00:30" }, { "01:00": "01:00" }}`.

I have trouble typing the reduce function below. How can I type `acc` or the return value of the function to avoid using `any` as type for `acc`?

```js
generateTimeIntervals(0, 1440, 30)
  .reduce((acc, val) => {
    acc[val] = val;
    return acc;
  }, {})
```

Comment: Your expected output is invalid. Array of objects make sense however object of objects doesn't.

Comment: Remember to put parentheses round the curly braces in the arrow function. Otherwise it won’t return an object but instead treat them as a code block with no return value.

Comment: @evolutionxbox there is no implicit return in the arrow function here

Comment: You are creating a single object with `"00:00"`, `"00:30"`etc as key. Do you want an array of objects instead?

Comment: @adiga the one line formatting fooled me.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> how can i type acc or the return value of the func to avoid using any as type for acc?

You'd do that by providing the type of the `{}` seed you're providing, for instance `Record<string, string>` (but the exact type isn't the point here, the point is that assigning a type is how you do what you asked):

```typescript
let result = generateTimeIntervals(0, 1440, 30).reduce((acc, val) => {
    acc[val] = val;
    return acc;
}, {} as Record<string, string>);
```

TypeScript will be able to follow the `reduce` call's logic sufficiently to type the return value for you based on that.

Alternatively, don't use `reduce` and just type `result`:

```typescript
let result: Record<string, string> = {};
for (const val of generateTimeIntervals(0, 1440, 30)) {
    result[val] = val;
}
```

Answer (score 17):

You can pass in the type as an argument to `reduce`:

```js
let result = generateTimeIntervals(0, 1440, 30).reduce<Record<string, string>>((acc, val) => {
  acc[val] = val;
  return acc;
}, {})
```

See an example here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZlQJwIZVQFRgFtUBJMPTAN2wBsBnACmwC4wQiAjLAGkU5aJ2XXogiDh3TAEpEAbwCwAKESJMqKCExIA2stWqAylEwwwyZtL7HT5xpyuIbZixGn7EAXWUBfZctoNNVR6EFooRABeFHQsXAJiMgosGgZGAAY+AEYAFhzMxABmdOkAOnUAExAIVAAeACVUCDhMCtr6Exc+DttkAD4+xmYICD5U2Ui++Q9sEZ1UzyjEVIBuD3VNbURZiDWlHz45H3clZWawejhA0to4CwAidVDw+74nsKhpIA

Comment: @AlexeySh. `generateTimeIntervals` isn't defined anywhere; of course it won't compile.

Comment: Thanks, this seems like the most idiomatic answer

Comment: Passing in the type to the reduce function `array.reduce<T>(...)` was all I needed, as the rest of the type inferences worked flawlessly. TS was still inferring the accumulator's type as the array type, (even when typing the initialValue like the first answer) until I did this. Much thanks!