# How to use TypeScript with Array.prototype.reduce correct?

Tags: javascript, typescript, reduce

I have the following `reduce` function and whatever I try is not removing the errors:

```js
interface ITask {
  id: string;
  was: string;
}
//sampleData:
const tasks = [
   {id: "a", was: "Foo"}, 
   {id: "b", was: "Foo"}, 
   {id: "c", was: "Bad"}
]; 
const uniqueList = tasks.reduce<>((acc, current) => {
  const x = acc.find((item: ITask) => item.was === current.was);
  return !x ? acc.concat(current) : acc;
}, []);
```

that gives me:

```
Property 'find' does not exist on type 'never'.
Property 'was' does not exist on type 'never'.
Property 'concat' does not exist on type 'never'.
```

It is absolutely logical for me, that the `current` value is of type `ITask` and the `accumulator` is of type `ITask[]|[]`. Thus, I tried:

```js
const uniqueList = tasks.reduce<>((acc: ITask[] | [], current: ITask) => {
  const x = acc.find((item: ITask) => item.was === current.was);
  return !x ? acc.concat(current) : acc;
}, []);
```

This gives:

```
Argument of type '(acc: ITask[] | [], current: ITask) => ITask[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(previousValue: never, currentValue: never, currentIndex: number, array: never[]) => never'.
  Type 'ITask[]' is not assignable to type 'never'.
Argument of type 'ITask' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ConcatArray<never>'.
  Type 'ITask' is missing the following properties from type 'ConcatArray<never>': length, join, slice
```

Edit:

---

From the Comments I tried:

```js
const uniqueList = tasks.reduce((acc, current: ITask) => {
  const x = acc.find((item: ITask) => item.was === current.was);
  return !x ? acc.concat(current) : acc;
}, [] as ITask[] | []);
```

This gives me:

```
Property 'find' does not exist on type 'never'.
Property 'concat' does not exist on type 'never'.
```

Comment: I believe the answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54117100/why-does-typescript-infer-the-never-type-when-reducing-an-array-with-concat

Comment: You just need to type the accumulator `...}, [] as ITask[]);` or `tasks.reduce<ITask[]>(...` [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=15&ssc=19&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBU4GcDWyDeAUMssACYBcyWYUoA5gNzHIDu2VNdIThAvoQD0grHAC2ABwA2EACJwwcCoQQB7EDWSLcWKhmw4A2gF1kAXmSGWBclQBEcOwBo2HZHYBiq1Xb4vr+LbuAEbOrrruXj5+yAFBdghh7BF2AEJwZL6ExoyxahpgyFAQWOaWpthomLgmzPmaAK4gwACODRAAMsCaFto4WAB0xWQNSAAUY4gILggNUMXgAJTmAHwELPWFAB5lUwMwoGQTwJBietU4y2ZrJxBiA8nmZhaz8xDgD9iLzCTFYHMgZAAQh2AH5kHt8ggFGNXgswMsqFNmDETBDSvoasZvkA)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [give type to accumulator with array reduce typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59321685/give-type-to-accumulator-with-array-reduce-typescript)

Comment: `[] as ITask[] | []` is not working either. It gives me the same errors as from the very first example without types. I updated my question.

Comment: I don't see any reference to `| []` did you try the playground?

Comment: Even without `|  []` is not changing anything. But I'm wondering as acc is [] in the first run.

Comment: type your `tasks` variable. The answer below and the playground I linked both work without errors

Comment: In my app my `tasks` is defined as `const [tasks, setTasks] = useState<ITask[] | []>([]);`

Comment: why the conditional? It should just be `useState<ITask[]>` unless you plan on storing something else in it?

Comment: Without `| []` it is working. But I'm wondering why as the array can be empty

Comment: any empty array still has a type. The type indicates that only elements of that type can be added to the array regardless of whether it has elements in it or not. Here is a [codesandox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gto9q) showing the types in React.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for reference here is an example of use within a React component using `useState`.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQBVMBnAazgG8AoORAEwC44SYpkBzAblrgHdSzVuyTdqAX2rVsEJKzgxSZEsyJKA2gF04AXjjrelBEzgAiTKYA0-QWYBiECKfHXDx5qYBGVmyvuPnVzojE1NsHwE-UwAhTHpnak0uOCkAelS4AHJFchJMxBIFAE8wYHo4TyK4AFcSYABlRVRqdJk5eHUc5Ws6mGJc7T1ahqbgAB41ci0APgAKLQBKHmlZeWqkBABHauAAGQR5PS6SADooMurcCf6yGdnZnGxrbGqoc5QF3WmqXjb5EF0cEeJ3QyHo9wQqAAtqobp8dN9IcAoSdIrodHoXm9gChUaQlrxzjBXkg4ABCAEAfiB2GwJza2EwMFmWPeME+zEePBc+k0SyAA)

```
export interface ITask {
  id: string;
  was: string;
}

const tasks: ITask[] = [
  {id: "a", was: "Foo"}, 
  {id: "b", was: "Foo"}, 
  {id: "c", was: "Bad"}
]; 

// 'tasks' is typed by useState
//const [tasks, setTasks] = useState<ITask[]>([]);

const uniqueList = tasks.reduce<ITask[]>((acc, current) => {
  const x = acc.find((item: ITask) => item.was === current.was);
  return !x ? acc.concat(current) : acc;
}, []);
```

See the full [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gto9q).

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export interface ITask {
  id: string;
  was: string;
}

interface IProps {
  [tasks: string]: ITask[];
}

export default function App({ tasks: _tasks }: IProps) {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState<ITask[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTasks(_tasks);
  }, [_tasks]);

  function uneek() {
    const uniqueList = tasks.reduce<ITask[]>((acc, current) => {
      const x = acc.find((item: ITask) => item.was === current.was);
      return !x ? acc.concat(current) : acc;
    }, []);
    setTasks(uniqueList);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Tasks</h1>
      {tasks.length
        ? tasks.map(({ id, was }) => (
            <div key={id}>
              <h4>{was}</h4>
            </div>
          ))
        : null}
      <button type="button" onClick={uneek}>
        uneek
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a few more type indicators. See this [stackblitz snippet](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-pdfh61?file=index.ts).

```
const tasks: ITask[] = [
//    ^ note: typo in question
   {id: "a", was: "Foo"},
   {id: "b", was: "Foo"},
   {id: "c", was: "Bad"},
]; 
const uniqueList: ITask[] = tasks.reduce<ITask[]>((acc: ITask[], current: ITask) => {
  const x = acc.find((item: ITask) => item.was === current.was);
  return !x ? acc.concat(current) : acc;
}, []);
```

Comment: This gives me `Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1` for `<ITask[]>`.

Comment: Add `: ITask[]` to `uniqueList` I suppose. See edited answer

Comment: When I remove the `| []` then it is working without issues even without `<ITask[]>`